# Can't send FileMessage to bale bot

Tags: bots, bale-messenger

Trying to send a file message to bale.ai bot. Upload seems working correctly but when it reach send function the connection will be reseted. What is the problem?

```
let ddd = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/a.html') 
bot.UploadFile(ddd,'file').then(response => {
let fileId = response.fileId
let fileAccessHash = response.accessHash
let fileٰVersion = response.version

const stats = fs.statSync(__dirname + '/a.html')
var file = new SDK.FileMessage(fileId, fileAccessHash, 'telename', stats.size, 'text/html', 'see')
bot.send(file, responder.peer)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

fileId and accessHash must be string, replace this line

```
var file = new SDK.FileMessage(fileId.toString(), fileAccessHash.toString(), 'telename', stats.size, 'text/html', 'see')
```

with yours.